# Cache request from shopify proxy

Tags: caching, nginx, shopify, fastcgi

I want to cache request from shopify App proxy. Here is what I try:

- Nginx with fastcgi enabled
- Requests direct to our site were cached successfully (HIT status)
- Requests through Shopify App proxy always failed (MISS status)

My configs:

nginx.conf

```
fastcgi_cache_path  /dev/shm/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=dev:200m inactive=60m max_size=500m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie X-Accel-Expires ;
```

vhost.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass            unix:/home/xxx.abc/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index           index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_cache dev;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie Vary X-Accel-Expires;
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    fastcgi_cache_valid 36h;
}
```

access.log when request to our server directly

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - HIT [17/Aug/2017:15:02:17 +0700]  "GET /comment/get_review?product_id=10461149960&shop_id=17224077&currentPage=4&shop=xxx.myshopify.com&path_prefix=%2Fa%2Fcomment&timestamp=1502955999&signature=89b33dcecfe1f418f038b5a671f5781332afa8d7c0c9a8a104db8929be10f015 HTTP/2.0" 200 1676 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
```

access.log when request through Shopify's App proxy

```
23.227.37.119 - MISS [17/Aug/2017:15:04:09 +0700]  "GET /comment/get_review?product_id=10461149768&shop_id=17224077&shop=quanstore1.myshopify.com&path_prefix=%2Fa%2Fcomment&timestamp=1502957049&signature=815b7ebf67e8a621c3057a53bd1dcd6d6a719a4cd43e4b0140855036066e0d18 HTTP/1.0" 200 8177 "https://quanstore1.myshopify.com/products/led-pet-safety-collar" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
```

I don't understand what going on here. Please help me. Thanks so much

PS: Sorry for my bad in English.

Comment: Leave logs line separate what is the actual issue? You not getting the right content or you getting no content?

Comment: Hi, the cache always miss when request through App Proxy of Shopify. You could see the access log above (xxx mean my actually IP, 23.227.37.119 is IP of Shopify's proxy - both request giving the same result)